# VC++ provides default 'delete' operator for each class if it is not defined

Tags: c++

I think VC++ compiler provides definition for 'delete' operator for every class if it is not provided by the programmer. Can anyone please confirm?

The generated dis assembly code in VC++ says that there is common 'new' operator for every class. However, 'delete' operator exist for each class. Here is the evidence:

```
delete bPtr;
// The dis assembly code generated by vc++ for above line    
....
**call        Base::`scalar deleting destructor' (411253h)** 
....

delete [] bPtrArr;

// The dis assembly code generated by vc++ for above line
....
**call        Base::`vector deleting destructor' (41125Dh)** 
....
```

Call Stack:

```
malloc.exe!Base::~Base()  Line 128
malloc.exe!Base::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x2b bytes
malloc.exe!wmain(int argc=0x00000001, wchar_t * * argv=0x00343250)  Line 173 + 0x2b bytes
malloc.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 579 + 0x19 bytes
malloc.exe!wmainCRTStartup()  Line 399
```

Comment: @Dew you should be careful in posing Question . I am sure you meant new and delete in lower case. But its better always to be specific and syntactically an semantically correct here along with word usage

Comment: The code in your edit is not evidence of a `delete` for each class. It just shows that there is a difference between `delete` for scalars and `delete []` for arrays. This is reasonable and expected.

Answer (score 4):

No. But `new` and `delete` (lower-case) are defined by the standard and have to be provided by the compiler. Classes that don't have their own versions defined use the default implementations.

Comment: The generated dis-assembly code make me feel that compiler provides 'delete' operator for each class.

Answer (score 1):

Both `operator new` and `operator delete` are either non-member functions or static member functions.* The only ones defined by default are in the global namespace. No class members are defined by default.

What you are seeing is the *deleting destructor*. This exists only in classes with virtual destructors. As well as destroying the most derived object, such a destructor frees the memory as if you used the `delete` operator directly on the most derived object. This cannot be done without a virtual dispatch, so `delete` is called from within the destructor — hence the name.

This is a specific kind of destructor, not an `operator delete` at all. It just *calls* `operator delete`, which already lives somewhere else.

**EDIT:** MSVC apparently also does it this way when the most derived type is statically known. This is a valid approach, but the rationale for having deleting destructors is still based on virtual destructors. In this case, a deleting destructor is always called by a `delete` expression, and a non-deleting destructor is called by anything else (`return` statement, derived class destructor, etc).

*(Although, confusingly, the `static` keyword is always implied when they are members, even if it's not written down.)

Comment: My 'Base' class has no virtual destructor/method.

Comment: @DewKumar: Huh. Well, Microsoft can do things that way, the Standard does allow it. Not a big difference.

Comment: Common method for 'delete' operator can also be provided as common 'new' method is provided :). I wanted to know why VC++ is not provide common 'delete' method.

Comment: @DewKumar It's a function, not a "method", and it's called `::operator delete()`. Try compiling a call directly and compare to the contents of the deleting destructor.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Since some others have "yes": **no**.

And that's important because it has very noticeable practical consequences.

The only operator that's automatically generated is the copy assignment operator `T& operator=( T const& )`. As a consequence of this operator being generated, base class assignment operators are by default hidden. If one needs such an operator to be available in a derived class, one needs to use `using` – which would not be needed if the operator was not automatically generated.

Now, you write "New" but there is no such in the language. There is **`new` keyword**, which is used in **`new` expressions**, and there is (a set of overloads of) `operator new`, which as opposed is an **allocation function**. For example, writing `new T()` allocates dynamically memory for an instance of class `T`, and constructs a `T` instance in that memory area, while `T::operator new` is just a call of the allocation function defined by `T`. It it defines one.

By default a `new` expression uses the global allocation function, the global `operator new`. But a class can define its own custom `operator new`. Which, if it is accessible so that the `new` expression compiles, is then called.